# Restoring MySql database from frm, ibd, trg files

Tags: mysql

I have a zip file with lots of frm, ibd and trg files.

It looks like I have one of each kind per table:

```
users.frm
users.ibd
users.trg
```

I want to restore a database using that files. I dont know what are they.

Any help?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28). it details a way of restoring just from a .ibd file. Further more, a mysql dump would not create the above files.

Comment: Is this guy manually creating the tables?

Comment: they are table defination files , you need to take mysqldump to resotre data. why you want to use these files to restore the data. Any reasons?

Comment: The database is too big and a sql dump does not work. The process just hangs.